# error on fnUpdate in jquery dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery dataTable in my application. once edit button is clicked it will pop up a dialog to edit the cell value. I'm using knockout for that. 
on the blur event I want that new value to be displayed on the table cell(Which is not knockout).
I'm using fnUpdate for that but still no luck on that. i'm getting "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node" error

here's my code

```
self.applyEditRate = function(bonus) {
            bonus.IsRateEditMode(false);
            var row = 1;//row index
            $('#table-bonus-data').dataTable().fnUpdate(bonus.BounsRate(), row, 4);
        };
```